# I have the same ngStyle for 2 different elements. How to overwrite them to keep the code DRY?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dry, ng-style

I want to overwrite ngstyle

```
            <p class="is-discount" [ngStyle]="{
                'background-color':
                  bike.discount > 70
                    ? 'red'
                    : bike.discount > 60
                    ? 'pink'
                    : bike.discount > 50
                    ? 'orange'
                    : null
              }">
              -{{ bike.discount }}%
            </p>
```

70
                        ? 'red'
                        : bike.discount > 60
                        ? 'pink'
                        : bike.discount > 50
                        ? 'orange'
                        : null
                  }">
                  -{{ bike.discount }}%

```
          <p [ngStyle]="{
              'color':
                bike.discount > 70
                  ? 'red'
                  : bike.discount > 60
                  ? 'pink'
                  : bike.discount > 50
                  ? 'orange'
                  : null
            }">
              {{
                bike.price - (bike.discount / 100) * bike.price
                  | currency: "EUR"
              }}
            </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same `ngStyle` on both elements. Make a variable in your `.ts` file of the component:

```
myStyle = {
           'color':
            bike.discount > 70
            ? 'red'
            : bike.discount > 60
            ? 'pink'
            : bike.discount > 50
            ? 'orange'
            : null
          }
```

and then you can use it in your `.html` file of your component like this:

```
<p class="is-discount" [ngStyle]="myStyle">
  -{{ bike.discount }}%
</p>
```